# Be Under An Obligation(Owe)

Tags: finance

Assalamualakum! I'm in big trouble!{Please consider my language.English isn't my first language.}
I am a family man who in most cases have to look after the affairs of the family. Even though I am the youngest of three brothers, I have to do the daily chores for the family. Which turn out to be my financial dealings with a lot of strangers outside. And to some of them, I owe a very little money. The saddest thing is that I've forgotten their appearance, I even tried a few times to guess the creditors .But every time I failed to repay them because unfortunately I've forgotten the look and address of the creditors.
And they are not coming to me to take their money. It seems that they have forgotten about this little money. This thing is constantly bothering me, I don't feel at peace for this. I can’t be respectful of myself, I always feel sinful. What do I do now? Is there any way to escape from this danger in Islam? Please show me the right Islamic path for the sake of Allah so that I can get rid of this mental anguish and at the same time the burden of this sin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah says in Quran;(Believers! Whenever you contract a debt from one another for  a known term, commit it to writing,.... And call upon  two of your men as witnesses; but if two men are not there,then let there be one man and two woman as witnesses from among those acceptable to you...)(2:282)
Because you have forgotten the names and appearance of those people , so first of all you should ask those people whom you meet normally like people at work with you , relatives, neighbors, friends,ask every single person you meet  in order to find those people Who has given you money and then give it to them.